# Phusion Passenger 2.2.2 crashes often

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, phusion

I deployed an rails(2.3.2) app on Passenger 2.2.2.
It crashes sometimes.

There's the error message.

```
Passenger encountered the following error: 
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Broken pipe 

Exception class: 
PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner::Error 
Backtrace: 
# File Line Location 
0 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb 117 in `spawn_application' 
1 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 265 in `spawn_rails_application' 
2 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 80 in `synchronize' 
3 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 79 in `synchronize' 
4 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 250 in `spawn_rails_application' 
5 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 153 in `spawn_application' 
6 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 282 in `handle_spawn_application' 
7 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 337 in `__send__' 
8 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 337 in `main_loop' 
9 /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 187 in `start_synchronously' 
10 /dh/passenger/bin/passenger-spawn-server 61
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824783/rails-app-randomly-crashes-with-error-premature-end-of-script-headers), you can run into this if you're hitting your memory limit on Dreamhost. If you're in a shared hosting environment I'd bet that's your issue.

Comment: I create an user for each rails app to avoid this memory limit issue. It's been ok so far.