# Premature end of script headers on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to deploy another rails app to my linode under a subdomain. I have an another rails app that is running previously. I have matched the settings up, but I can't find why it keeps throwing this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your     request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

with the rails logs not capturing anything and the apache log captures:

```
Premature end of script headers
```

I'm using Passenger with Apache. Rail 4.1. And MySQL.

Comment: Can you make a local request using curl? `curl http://localhost:3000` (or whatever port your Passenger is running on)? Also check your memory usage, as mentioned in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/832271/148844

Comment: Hi, the memory usage seems to be fine. When I curl, I get the same Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you post the transcript? The 'Internal Server Error' is an Apache error, not a Rails error. Make the curl request to your Rails server.

Comment: The entire apache log consists of "Premature end of script headers". When I run the server locally and curl, it works. But thats on development. So I don't know how to access that from my browser. If i change it production, it goes back to the original issue

Comment: So you are telling me that there is absolutely no way for you to log into production and run curl from the command line, correct?